Verifying that a second-order cone is proper.
I recently came across the mention that a second-order cone
$$\mathcal{K}= \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n \big\vert x^TKx\leq0, c^Tx\geq 0 \}$$
with $K\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ could be verified to be proper if the eigenvalues of $K$ were such that
(1) $n-1$ of them had a positive real part,
(2) none were imaginary,
(3) exactly one has a negative real part.
I was wondering if this proposition is true, and if so, what steps someone would need to follow in order to demonstrate it?
